# Retornar intervalo de números de acordo com a divisão do total de números por um número inteiro

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

**Dada a seguinte situação:**

Preciso criar uma função que receba como parâmetro *(um valor int e um divisor int)*.
A idéia é popular um array com o TOTAL do intervalo passado para a função.
Isso eu consegui fazer. No entanto, preciso agora retornar o intervalo desses valores com base na divisão entre o número passado como parâmetro e o valor da divisão. Exemplificarei abaixo:

```js
const sort = (totalImage, totalPeople) => {
    let imageList = new Array;
    var result;
    for (let interval = 1; interval <= totalImage; interval++) {
        let intervalValue = parseInt(interval);
        imageList.push(intervalValue);
    }
    result = totalImage / totalPeople;
```

Tentei uma abordagem com o método slice(), mas não obtive sucesso. 
Desde já, agradeço qualquer colaboração e espero ter ilucidado da melhor forma possível o problema.

Comment: Seu problema está muito obscuro. 
1º -  "A idéia é popular um array com o TOTAL do intervalo passado para a função." `Esse intervalo é simplesmente o intervalo de valores que vai de 1 a totalImage, correto?`

2º - "No entanto, preciso agora retornar o intervalo desses valores com base na divisão entre o número passado como parâmetro e o valor da divisão". `Qual a relação, exatamente, que tem entre os elementos desse array e a divisão entre os dois parâmetros da função?`

Comment: 1. Exatamente.
2. Então, o primeiro parâmetro seria um número total de imagens. E o segundo parâmetro, seria, por exemplo, a divisão do total de imagens pelo número de pessoas.

Exemplo de chamada da função:
Sort(20, 4) 

output:

onePerson = 1,2,3,4,5;
secondPerson = 6,7,8,9,10;
ThirdPerson = 11,12,13,14,15;
fourthPerson = 16,17,18,19,20;

Comment: E se os números não forem uma divisão exata, tipo Sort(20, 3)?

Comment: A princípio, seria feito apenas com divisão exata. Mas no caso de uma divisão não exata, a ideia era arredondar para baixo os valores ceil(), por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `.slice()` para fatiar a array de acordo com o número de pessoas (segundo argumento passado à função) inserindo numa nova array os valores em cada índice dessa nova array. Seria algo parecido com a função [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-chunk.php) do PHP.

Use o `Math.floor()` na divisão para arrendondar para baixo em casos onde a divisão não seja exata.

Veja:

```js
const sort = (totalImage, totalPeople) => {
   let imageList = new Array;
   for (let interval = 1; interval <= totalImage; interval++) {
      let intervalValue = parseInt(interval);
      imageList.push(intervalValue);
   }   
   let result = Math.floor(totalImage / totalPeople);

   let sliced = new Array; // cria nova array
   
   for(let x = 0; x < totalImage; x+=result){
      sliced.push(imageList.slice(x, x+result).join()); // aqui fatia e converte em string
   }
   
   return sliced;
}

console.log(sort(20,4));
console.log(sort(20,3));
```

Comment: Eu estava no caminho certo! Muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda, Sam! Só não vi a necessidade da variável i como um contador.

Comment: É verdade. O i era teste eu acabei esquecendo de remover do código.